# OGRE3D not working in visualstudio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ogre

So I tried installing OGRE3D sdk for Visualstudio 2015. 
I followed the installation tutorial link given below.

[OGRE_3D_sdk](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Installing+the+Ogre+SDK)

The SDK I downloaded was OGRE 1.9 SDK for visualstudio 2012(32 bit) [OGRE1.9_SDK](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/sdk)

and installed in `C:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0` .
DirectX was downloaded from the link in the tutorial.
I set the environment variable `OGRE_HOME` to `C:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0` . I then loaded the `OGRE.sln` in VisualStudio, everything was loaded successfully. But when trying to run the `samplebrowser` , it doesn't compile and gives 364 error messages, and 443 warnings, some of which are given below.

```
Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in BezierPatch.obj    Sample_BezierPatch  C:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\Samples\BezierPatch\libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib(error_code.obj) 1   


Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in BSP.obj    Sample_BSP  C:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\Samples\BSP\libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib(error_code.obj) 1   


Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1900' in Dot3Bump.obj   Sample_Dot3Bump C:\OgreSDK_vc11_v1-9-0\Samples\Dot3Bump\libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib(error_code.obj)    1
```

Where did I mess up? If there's something wrong(which definitely is) , then please provide me with information to properly set this up and running for VS 2015. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, your SDK version was built with VS2012 which means the resulting binaries do not work with VS2015 directly. This applies not only to Ogre3D but all libraries/binaries in general.

Two options:

1. Build Ogre3D from source with VS2015.
2. Change the platform toolset settings for your project to mimic VS2012: Project properties => Configuration Properties => General => Platform Toolset.

*Disclaimer: I am not completely sure if the second option will or should* work.

Comment: Wow, it is surprising that you also come to this forum too.  Thank for your hard work, Philip Allgaier, one of the great Ogre3D developers.